# Почему в место результата самого запроса, записывается сам запрос в TextBlock?

Tags: c#

У меня есть класс с публичными полями

```
public class DateUser
{
    public static string Name { get; set; }
    public static string SurName { get; set; }
    
}
```

Пытаюсь в эти поля записать значения которые должны получится при выполнении запроса

```
//заполнение полей
                        DateUser.Name = Convert.ToString(App.DataBase.SchoolBoys.
                        SqlQuery($"Select b.Name From SchoolBoy b Where  EXISTS(Select 1 From SchoolAndTeachers s Where s.IdSchool = b.Id And s.Login = '{tBLogin.Text}')"));


                        DateUser.SurName = Convert.ToString(App.DataBase.SchoolBoys.
                        SqlQuery($"Select b.SurName From SchoolBoy b Where  EXISTS(Select 1 From SchoolAndTeachers s Where s.IdSchool = b.Id And s.Login = '{tBLogin.Text}')"));
```

И вот что он записывает
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сами запросы рабочие

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот запись в текст блок

```
NameAndSyrName.Text = (DateUser.Name + " " + DateUser.SurName).ToString();
```

Это код прописан в файле App.xaml.cs

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public static readonly Entities.LibraryEntities DataBase = new Entities.LibraryEntities();
}
```

Comment: Что такое `App.DataBase.SchoolBoys.SqlQuery`?

Comment: @aepot. вот код

  `public partial class App : Application
    {
        public static readonly Entities.LibraryEntities DataBase = new Entities.LibraryEntities();
    }`

Это позволяет подключатся к sql server,  сам код рабочий который я кидал в вопросе, переходит в нужное окно в соответствии с веденным логином и паролем, но данные конкретные в публичных полях, он не правильно записывает.


**SchoolBoys** это название таблицы.  **SqlQuery()** это метод содержащий запрос.   **DataBase** Это переменная которая содержит название базы **LibraryEntities()**.

Comment: А что за библиотека?

Comment: @aepot, это и есть база которая находит в seq server.  Вот ссылка на проект https://github.com/crushednat123/test.git

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё вопрос решён

```
DateUser.Name = user.Teacher.Name; 
DateUser.SurName = user.Teacher.SurName;
```